# Why is this Ada type definition causing an compilation error?

Tags: types, ada

The definition of type `B` is equal to the definition of type `A`, it is just a shorter form. It works flawlessly.

So I assumed the definition of type `D` is again equal to the definition of type `C`. Yet, it throws the compiler errror printed below. Why that?

### Program Text:

```
type range_T is range 0 .. 255;
type A       is array (range_T)  of Integer;
type B       is array (0 .. 255) of Integer;

type enum_T is (N, S, W, O);
type C      is array (enum_T)     of Integer;
type D      is array (N, S, W, O) of Integer;
```

### Compiler console output:

```
$gnatmake hello.adb 2>&1

gcc -c hello.adb
hello.adb:12:27: invalid subtype mark in discrete range
hello.adb:12:30: invalid subtype mark in discrete range
hello.adb:12:33: invalid subtype mark in discrete range
hello.adb:12:36: invalid subtype mark in discrete range
gnatmake: "hello.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: `type D is array (N, S, W, O) of Integer;` is the syntax for a 4-dimensional array--or at least it would be if `N`, `S`, `W`, and `O` were types or subranges (`subtype N is integer range 1..5` or something like that).  Note that a problem with your assumption is that `B` uses `0..255` as the index subrange, while the definition of `range_T` is `range 0..255`--so they were never identical in any case.

Comment: @ajb: Thanks for your input on the 4-dimensional array! Multi-dimensional arrays are something I did not think of in this context. Could you further elaborate what you wrote on the definitions of `B` and `range_T`? Unfortunately it's not yet fully clear to me. You said that the were never identical in any case. So in which way do the types `A` and `B` differ from each other?

Comment: The types `A` and `B` aren't different.  I was referring to the assumption you made that you could copy the text of the type definition to the array index.  But the text of the `range_T` type is `range 0 .. 255`, and the text in the array index of B is `0 .. 255` without the `range` keyword, so you shouldn't have assumed that you should be able to copy the text in the second case.  That's all I was trying to say.

Comment: A and B differ because they are made in different places (I originally wrote “because they are different” :). You couldn’t assign a value of type B to a variable of type A. This would be true even if the type definitions were actually identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `N, S, W, O` is not a range. By the [syntax rules](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-6.html), it's treated as a sequence of index_subtype_definitions - which it's apparently not.

The proper syntax (mirroring the first set of definitions in your question) is this:

```
type enum_T is (N, S, W, O);
type C      is array (enum_T)     of Integer;
type D      is array (N .. O)     of Integer;
```